# Python Minecraft Launcher Ely.by

Tags: python, launcher

Help me write code for authorization through the Ely.by skin system for the python launcher

I tried to rewrite the code from php to python but it didn’t work, I also looked for information on the Internet but couldn’t find it. I would like that when you click on the button, a registration site opens and as a result there is an account in the application

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: "*Help me write code*" isn't going to get you very var here, when you haven't shared anything that you've done or asked any specific question. Start with the [tour], then learn how to write a [mcve] with all details, and not just a high level set of requirements.